# Get current post_id on or before init hook in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Im looking for anyway to get the current page id by the time the init hook fires.

The closest I've come is grabbing the $_POST['post_id'] when init hits admin-ajax.php but its unreliable... It often doesn't get set the first page load and requires a refresh for some reason.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the 'after_setup_theme' hook, which executes just before 'init'. Then, in a function triggered by that hook, you can get the current page ID like this:

```
// Get access to the current WordPress object instance
global $wp;

// Get the base URL
$current_url = home_url(add_query_arg(array(),$wp->request));

// Add WP's redirect URL string
$current_url = $current_url . $_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL'];

// Retrieve the current post's ID based on its URL
$id = url_to_postid($current_url);
```

Comment: im getting Undefined index: REDIRECT_URL

Comment: Hm, that's weird. Can you provide a pastebin showing both the hook and function that you wrapped around the code above?

Comment: I ended up just using QUERY_STRING and parse_url